# VF: apex:selectList - Using values in SOQL Query

Tags: visualforce, soql

I am getting the following error when trying to use the values passed from a VF page to the controller in a SOQL filter.

```
Invalid bind expression type of List<String> for column of type String
```

Here is my controller code (trimmed):

```
public class LicensingGridController {

    public Id selectedAccId {get; set;}
    public Boolean AccRendered {get; set;}
    public String stFilter {get; set;}
    public String bcsFilter {get; set;}
    list<BCS__c>hubs = new list<BCS__c>();
    String[] states = new String[]{};

        public LicensingGridController(){
            AccRendered     = FALSE;
            selectedAccId   = null;
            stfilter        = null;
        }

    public List<BCS__c> getTheHubs() {
        system.debug('stfilter = ' + stFilter);
        system.debug('states = '+ states);

        if(states == null || states == ''){
            hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,User__r.SmallPhotoUrl,
                    (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                     FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                    (Select Name,Status__c 
                     FROM Licenses__r)
                    FROM BCS__c
                    WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE];
            return hubs;
        } else {            
            hubs = [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,
                    (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                     FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                    (Select Name,Status__c 
                     FROM Licenses__r
                    )
                    FROM BCS__c
                    WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE AND 
                    id in (select Hub_Name__c from LIcense__c where Name IN(:states) AND Status__c = 'Current')];
            return hubs;
        }

    }
```

The problem line is:

```
WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE AND 
                        id in (select Hub_Name__c from LIcense__c where Name IN(:states) AND Status__c = 'Current')];
```

Here is debug for "states" value:

```
10:29:57:074 USER_DEBUG [18]|DEBUG|states = (MISSOURI, FLORIDA)
```

Comment: try putting a colon for in the query like the following,                          WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE AND 
                        id in :(select Hub_Name__c from LIcense__c where Name IN(:states) AND Status__c = 'Current')];

Comment: Nope, that generated a different error.
unexpected token: 'select'

I have had this working with a basic string variable. I just can't figure out how to get it to accept a list of values instead.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses. Just use `Name IN :states`

Comment: can you post your vf page code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `states` is bound to the selectList, you can just do this:

```
public class LicensingGridController {

    public Id selectedAccId {get; set;}
    public Boolean AccRendered {get; set;}
    public String stFilter {get; set;}
    public String bcsFilter {get; set;}
    public String[] states { get; set; }

        public LicensingGridController(){
            AccRendered     = FALSE;
        }

    public BCS__c[] getTheHubs() {
        return [Select Id, Name, User__r.Name,
                    (Select Id,Account__c,Account__r.Name,Hub_Name__r.Name
                     FROM Account_Counselors__r),
                    (Select Name,Status__c 
                     FROM Licenses__r
                    )
                    FROM BCS__c
                    WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE AND 
                    id in (select Hub_Name__c from LIcense__c where Name IN :states AND Status__c = 'Current')];
    }
```

When no states are selected, the Name IN :states binding will be ignored.

Comment: I like your solution and it does work however at page load, before anything is selected in list, my table is now blank. Is there a way to have it return all like my  if() else() method did?

Comment: @MattM That's odd. Seems like the behavior's changed in 37.0. You might still need the if-else after all.

Comment: My class is set to 36. I don't have 37 yet.

Comment: @MattM Well, maybe it's just been a while since I've experimented with it. I'll do some more research on it. For now, though, I don't see a problem with using an if-else statement to just get it done.

Comment: Cool, I will run with that. Thanks for the other help.